# Could not connect to SQL Server from windows app

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to connect my Windows Forms app with SQL Server remotely.

But I am getting following exception:

> The underlying provider failed on open.
>
> InnerException:
>
> The network path was not found.

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="dbEntities" 
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=serverip;Database=dbname;User ID=myuser;Password=mypass;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

It is connecting with my local database, but not with database on server.

I have checked on server all sql services are running and TCP/IP is enabled and there is also a rule for sql port in firewall.

Is there something that I am missing?

Please guide me.

Thank you.

Comment: The error "Network path was not found" is your keyword for your answer. Are you sure you are trying to connect to existing path directory? or does the sql server credentials (Sql server name and password) matches from your sql server on the your server and to your connection string declared?

Comment: Yes, credentials are correct.

Comment: 'Network path is not found' is not usually an error you would see when connecting to a network server. Can you post the line of code that it is failing on. Can you complete a test connection to the network server in SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

Does it accepts sql server authentication or windows authentication on the remote machine you are attempting to connect? Sometimes the server is configured to receive only windows authentication connections and I see that you are connecting with a user and a password I asume it's a database user, if it is the problem can be solved by review the remite connections to both windows and sql server authentications